# SQL Return rows with highest value for a given field

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I was practising some SQL with this example data:

employee_data

```
salary    first_name    department
50000     Adam          Sales
27000     Beth          HR
70000     Dave          IT
52000     Amy           Sales
etc...
```

I wrote a query to return the records with the highest salary for each department. However, for some of the departments there were two or more people tied for the highest salary. So I wrote this short script:

```
WITH cte AS( 
SELECT salary, first_name, department, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY department) AS rownum
FROM employee_data
WHERE salary IN (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employee_data GROUP BY department)
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rownum = 1
```

This does return the correct output being only taking one record for each department where there is a tie for the highest salary. But I was wondering, is there a more efficient way to do it? With less lines or without the need to include a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

The RANK function is more suited for this scenario eg

```sql
WITH cte AS( 
    SELECT 
        salary, 
        first_name, 
        department, 
        RANK() OVER(
             PARTITION BY department
             ORDER BY salary DESC
        ) AS rnk
    FROM 
        employee_data
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: The query runs fine but it doesn't quite give the desired outcome. For example in the data, there are two different people called Steve who have the joint highest salary in the HR department. This query returns both of them

Comment: If you only need 1 person then you don't need the subquery in your where clause `WHERE salary IN (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employee_data GROUP BY department)` you only need to add the order by clause in `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY department ORDER BY salary DESC)`. If you would like to break or order the tie by a different column you may add that to the order by clause

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter where `Rank()` and `row_number()` are 1 for a department

```
select 
first_name,
salary,
department_name
from
(Select
first_name,
salary,
department_name
row_number()over(partition by department_name order by salary desc) as rn,
rank()over(partition by department_name order by salary desc) as rnk
from table)a
where rn=1 and rnk=1;
```